# Canvas logic issue

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've started to learn how to use canvas since 2 days now and here I am... stuck !

I wanted to create an algo which would draw a "tree", starting from bottom and expanding up.

Here is my code :

```
var newX = 0;
var baseTaille = 20;
var lines = [];
var maxLines = 20;
var baseLifeTime = 50;
var timer = 0;

function Point (x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
function Line(origin,direction,taille,ancestor,endingPoint)
{
  this.origin = new Point(origin.x,origin.y);
  this.direction = direction;
  this.taille = taille;
  this.ancestor = ancestor;
  this.endingPoint = new Point(endingPoint.x,endingPoint.y);
  this.lifeTime = taille;
}
var canvas;
var context;
$(document).ready(function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  $("#canvas").attr("width",$(window).width());
  $("#canvas").attr("height",$(window).height());
  init();

});



function init () {
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
      })();
      animate();
}
var directions = {
    'UP' : 1,
    'FLAT' : 0
}

function animate() {

  // update
  if(timer == 0)
  {
      if (lines.length == 0) {
        createLine(directions.UP,null,50);
      }else
      {
        if(lines.length < maxLines)
        {
            //If the previous line is in the "FLAT" direction, create 2 lines UP
            if (lines[lines.length-1].direction == directions.FLAT) {
                var p = lines[lines.length-1];
                p.endingPoint.x = lines[lines.length-1].origin.x;
                createLine(directions.UP,p,10);
                createLine(directions.UP,lines[lines.length-2],15); 
            }

            if (lines[lines.length-1].direction == directions.UP) {
                createLine(directions.FLAT,lines[lines.length-1],100);
            }
        }else
        {

        }
      }
      timer = baseLifeTime;
    }
  // clear
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // draw stuff
  for(var l in lines){

    var line = lines[l];
    drawLine(context,line);
  }
  // request new frame
  requestAnimFrame(function() {
    animate();
    timer--;
  });
}

function drawLine (context,line) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(line.origin.x, line.origin.y);
    if(line.direction == directions.UP)
    {
        if(line.lifeTime > 0)
        {
            context.lineTo(line.endingPoint.x, line.endingPoint.y+line.lifeTime);
        }
        else
        {
            context.lineTo(line.endingPoint.x, line.endingPoint.y);
        }
    }
    if(line.direction == directions.FLAT)
    {
        if(line.lifeTime > 0)
        {
            context.lineTo(line.endingPoint.x-line.lifeTime, line.endingPoint.y);
        }
        else
        {
            context.lineTo(line.endingPoint.x, line.endingPoint.y);
        }
    }


    //context.globalAlpha = line.lifeTime/baseLifeTime;

    line.lifeTime--;

    context.strokeStyle = '#eee';
    context.stroke();
        //else
    //{
      //lines.splice(l,1);
    //}
}

function createLine (direction,ancestor,taille) {
    //TODO if !ancestor, we create the first "branch" of our tree
    var origin;
    if(ancestor == null)
    {
        origin = {
            'x':($(window).width()/2),
            'y':($(window).height())
        };

        endingPoint = {
            'x':origin.x,
            'y':(origin.y-taille)
        };
        ancestor = null;
    }else
    {
        if (direction == directions.UP){
            origin = ancestor.endingPoint;

            endingPoint = {
                'x':origin.x,
                'y':(origin.y-taille)
            };
        }

        if (direction == directions.FLAT)
        {
            origin = {
                'x':(ancestor.endingPoint.x-(taille/2)),
                'y':ancestor.endingPoint.y
            };

            endingPoint = {
                'x':(origin.x+taille),
                'y':(origin.y)
            };

        }
    }

    //We add the line to the "lines" array;
    lines.push(new Line(origin,direction,taille, ancestor,endingPoint));
}
```

http://pastebin.com/Xxq99vuC
and a codepen with it :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/facmg

As you can see, the first line is well created but then ...
I can't understand why the "flat" lines don't stay drawn after it's "lifetime" property goes to 0.

So I wondered if anyone could help me.

Thanks a lot. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
if (lines[lines.length-1].direction == directions.FLAT) {
    var p = lines[lines.length-1];
    p.endingPoint.x = lines[lines.length-1].origin.x;
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with `p.endingPoint.x = lines[lines.length-1].origin.x`, but it's setting the endingPoint of the previously created "flat" line to be the same as its origin, which makes it invisible.

If you remove that [all of the lines stay visible](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lKiCw), though I don't know how you intended them to appear exactly.

In general note that `var p = lineObject` in javascript creates a new *reference* to the lineObject, not a *copy* of it; so alterations you make to `p` will also be made to `line`. You may need to rethink the whole programme design as the way that lines link to their 'ancestors' seems to be causing problems.

Comment: Thank you a lot !!! didn't knew this, I found a way to clone my object and I did my ancestor check by adding a gaveBirth property to my lines. So I cycle through my lines and create some when the line has not "gave birth". http://codepen.io/anon/pen/facmg but now I wonder how to handle the animation speed =s

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you simply want whatever you draw to stay on the canvas :

```
  ...
  // clear
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  // Remove this
  // draw stuff
  for(var l in lines){
  ...
```

Removing the line `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` should do it.

Comment: Thanks,Your solution is great but I want to keep printing all of my lines because I want to add a fadeOut effect.

Comment: @AntoineGuillien I suggest fading out differently. A white shape on top of the whole canvas should do the trick.

Comment: On the one hand, if the OP really doesn't need to redraw everything on each frame he can radically simplify the programme (not just remove the `context.clearRect`). On the other hand, if there is any chance of doing more complicated animation, then he should probably stick to the conventional approach of blanking the canvas and redrawing all of the objects each time.

Comment: There is no *conventional approach of blanking the canvas and redrawing all of the objects each time*. That happens to be a way adopted to substitute refreshing of screen buffer. The OP is here is trying to generate more of an animation & not a game.